# Can one obtain from the following diagram that the map $f_3$ is injective?

Tags: commutative-algebra, diagram-chasing

Let $A_i$ and $B_i$ be $R$-modules $(i=1,2,3)$.
If in the diagram

[image]

each map is $R$-linear, the rows are exact, both squares commute, and $f_1, f_2, \alpha_1, \beta_1$ are injective, is it possible to prove that $f_3$ is injective?

Comment: @AnginaSeng: I have an explicit description of $f_3$. However, I was having problems proving it injective. I figured there might be an easier way to prove it injective using an argument based only on a diagram chase. I figured it might be wishful thinking, but didn't see no harm in asking the question anyway.

Comment: From snaky considerations, you also need the map from $\text{coker}\,f_1$ to $\text{coker}\,f_2$ to be injective.

Comment: Do you know the [snake lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_lemma)?

Comment: @Bernard: It's been such a long time that I would only say that I have heard of it and would be inclined to refresh my memory if it would help to prove the result.

Comment: But it is false in general (cf@Angina Seng's comment above).

Comment: Of course, since the horizontal lines are short exact sequences.

Comment: @Bernard: Apologies, I'm desperate for a proof and writing comments without thinking.

Comment: You need further hypotheses to prove it, since we have the long exact sequence provided  by the snake lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_1=B_3=0$, $A_2=A_3=B_1=B_2=R$ and $f_2$ the identity map (the other $f_i$
have to be zero maps). Then $\ker f_3=A_3=R$.